# How can I execute a string in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, procedure

I how can I execute the symbol `'+`?

I want to write a function so the input will be some string, for example - `'+`
and the return value will be: `#<procedure:+>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call  `eval` to evaluate quoted expressions

```
> (eval (read))
(+ 3 4)  ; your input
7

> (eval '+)
#<procedure:+>
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but it is an extremely bad idea to use `eval` if you don't know what you're doing.  Your soul will be sold, and puppies will get killed.  More concretely, if this is a homework, then `eval` is almost certainly the wrong answer.  (If it is, then leave the course and ask for a refund.)